# Kafka Connect JDBC Source OutOfMemoryError

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm running the following job with the [Confluent JDBC-Source connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html):

```
{
    "name": "jobName",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "timestamp.column.name": "dateColumn",
        "topic.prefix": "connect-test.",
        "connection.password": "pw",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.user": "un",
        "poll.interval.ms": "300000",
        "name": "jobName",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://serverName;Database=dbName;user=un;password=pw",
        "table.whitelist": "tableName"
    }
}
```

I have a similar Kafka-Connect job running successfully against the same DB and with the same user, but with another smaller table. So connection isn't the issue.

In the log on the Kafka-connect server running the job, I see this:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "KafkaBasedLog Work Thread - connect-configs"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | connect-cluster"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "KafkaBasedLog Work Thread - connect-offsets"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-3"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-4-thread-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "KafkaBasedLog Work Thread - connect-status"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "DistributedHerder"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-1-thread-5"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@2c243a24Timer"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp1434297727-21"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp1434297727-26"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp1434297727-27"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-14"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-15"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-1-thread-4"
```

So, not much to go on. The server that was running this job is now unresponsive, and not responding to REST calls. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Log into each connect worker over SSH or however you get there
2. Forcibly stop the Kafka Connect process
3. `export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` to something larger than the defaults on every server running Kafka Connect. For example `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx4G"`. Assuming Linux, then best place would be a bashrc file for a `kafka` user.
4. Run `connect-distributed` again as the user you exported the variable for

You may additionally want to export more values for enabling JMX to be exposed. This way, you can monitor the process before it crashes

Comment: I'm launching Kafka Connect via systemd. I added the following `Environment="KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx4G"`

Comment: This didn't fix the issue. Same crash.

Comment: Maybe increase `Xms`, but, how much data is being returned by the query that's running? I see you're not running any given query in that configuration, so are you scanning the entire table? Maybe lower the poll interval so it reads less data at once. Also, did you enable JMX and watch a graph of the memory usage?